# LOB Target for Azure BizTalk Service

Tags: azure, biztalk-services

I am trying to build a SQL LOB target in Azure BizTalk Services, initially I tried to create one through the Visual Studio and ran into the below error:

```
Message: 'Error occurred while trying to bring up the relay service.
Error Message: 'The remote name could not be resolved: 'xxxxxx-ns-sb.accesscontrol.windows.net'
```

This is because to create an LOB target we require an Services bus which is authenticated using ACS, but from August 2014 the support for ACS authenticated SB has been replaced by SSA.

The workaround I found at several places was to use Azure PowerShell to create a new SB, but as it turns out the new Azure PowerShell SDK doesn't recognize the command itself -

```
New-AzureSBNamespace : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'CreateACSNamespace'. 

New-AzureSBNamespace : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'useAcs'.
```

Any pointers workarounds here would really help.

Answer (score 0):

I finally was able to create a ACS namespace using the below command -

New-AzureSBNamespace -Name 'testLOB' -Location 'South Central US'

it doesnt take any other parameters, please be advised.